# Apache2 restart error on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

while i am trying to restart my apache2 configuration the system display this error on my ubuntu.

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 263 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/jobeet.local: No such file or directory Action 'configtest' failed. The Apache error log may have more information. ...fail!
```

Comment: Read the error message. Fix the problem. (seriously, this is pretty obvious. As a [professional](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5475/why-professional-capacity) you should not need to be spoon-fed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is clear: on line 263 of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, you likely included `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/jobeet.local`, and either that file does not exist, or apache doesn't have the correct permissions to read the file.